# VB6 callback Sub's relation to calling win32 thread, and vice versa

Tags: multithreading, winapi, vb6

A function in a win32 process (call it void cCB()) calls a VB6 Sub (call it vb6S, which receives some numeric data type data from cCB.  cCB originally received vb6S reference via AddressOf.

I've got two basic newbie questions about this:

Question 1: Is cCB's thread blocked by the call while vb6S() executes its code?

Question 2: Will VB have any "issues" if cCB's thread terminates and cCB's 
            memory is de-allocated before vb6S has completed its work?

***EDIT***:
In response to the request for code (and thanks for that downvote), here is the issue:

The task is a microsecond timer, to be used to unblock the WM queue of two VB IDE's when debugging two VB apps that are communicating via WM_COPYDATA messages.

That is: there are apps Alice and Bob.  When Alice sends Bob a wm74 (WM_COPYDATA) message, Bob hooks on to it, saves the information in the copydatastruct, and then is finished with the message.  The problem is that, now, in debugging, both Alice's and Bob's message queues are blocked as long is either debugger is at a break point.  It doesn't take long to kill one or both IDE's at that point.

So what I want to implement is an old Java Applet trick:  Bob calls out of process, which waits a tiny slice of time, and calls back in.  While out of process, Bob can release the message, the app/IDE tells Windows the message is handled, and Alice can go about her business.  To do this, before returning, Bob's message handler calls into a win32 DLL function, say:

`typedef void (__stdcall *FUNCPTR)(int);`

`void __stdcall ExecuteCallback(FUNCPTR cbAddress, double microS){};`

which Bob calls as

`ExecuteCallback AddressOf My74Processor, 250`

where My74Processor contains the app logic to process the string according to the cases in the code number that Alice put in the message structure.

ExecuteCallback grabs an existing timingWork code object from a queue of those, and puts it into a queue of threads via a workQueue manager that knows to start the thread at the proper point in the timingWork class.

After the timingWork timer clocks 250 microseconds (in this case) via watching QueryPerformanceCounter, it calls back to Bob's Sub at

`Sub My74Processor(ByVal reason as Long)`

and terminates.  The timingWork object is not destroyed; the last thing it does is put itself back in the queue of available objects.  The thread, on the other hand, terminates, and is available in the thread queue for more, maybe different, work when its turn comes around again.

Back with Bob, there is a breakpoint set in the processing code down in Sub My74Processor.  My questions, then, are in this context:

(a) when that breakpoint is hit, and the programmer takes some time to check variables and logic, and then continues the process, will all be fine in Bob's IDE's stack after My74Processor ends?

(b) when the timingWork routine makes the call back, will that thread be blocked?

I'm virtually certain the answer to (b) is "no."  I'm worried about, and not experienced enough with VB6 to know the answer to that.

**EDIT2** @wqw, I came to the same conclusion as I was going to sleep last night, but not for the correct reasons you state in your comment.

How about this: use the same out of process call, only instead of a callback function, send cCB information for it to send a WM_COMMAND message to VB6S, spoofing a state change of one of its controls, say a button, butCB? Then ExecuteCallback(..) becomes ExecuteClickback(..)

`void __stdcall ExecuteClickback(WORD butID, HANDLE hBut, HANDLE hVB6S, double microS){};`

The timerWork object does a `PostMessage` of a WM_COMMAND to hVB6S's Form with:

`wParam = (DWORD) ( (butID << sizeof(WORD)) + (WORD) BN_CLICKED ); lParam = hBut;`

Then, VB6S's form should raise its butCB_Click() event. That event handler would have the instruction to call My74Processor(). Since VB6S is necessarily in a pure message wait state once the call to ExecuteClickback is made, the arrival of the WM_COMMAND should "look" to VB6S just like the user actually clicked the button.

Comment: Can we see some actual code please?

Comment: You do what the Man says.  And, in fact, unless and until MSFT pulls VBA as the language behind Excel -which corporate America would not tolerate any time soon-, VB{A/6} is the Latin of programming languages: obsolete, unsupported, and yet every day masses are said in it.

Comment: `vb6S` has to be called back on the thread that executed `cCB` on init so all the thread-pool stuff above is not going to fly. You can execute VB6 code (callback) only on COM STA thread on which VB runtime is initialized, that is a STA on which a VB6 object has been created via DLLs class factory. VB6 globals are TLS, so on each thread there is a "new world" for the callback function so you have call it on the original thread to be useful in any way besides `Beep`ing.